# Different Style of captions

Tags: listings, captions

I am writing a document where I have different types of figures like tables and listings. To get the captions the way I want I wrote the following in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf, justification=raggedright, format=hang]{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{position=below}
\captionsetup[figure]{position=below}
```

Now I have seen that the captions on listings and tables look different than in the image

[image: different type of captions]

Shouldn't the `\usepackage[...]{caption}` instruction change the style all of the captions in the document?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[
    12pt, % font size
    ngerman, % german umlaute and german hyphenation
    a4paper, % paper format
    oneside, % one-sided pages
]{article}

% Code
\usepackage{listings} % source code
%\usepackage{bera} % optional: just to have a nice mono-spaced font
\usepackage{xcolor}

% colors
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{.9,.9,.9}
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{.4,.4,.4}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.65, 0.12, 0.82}
\definecolor{orangered}{rgb}{255, 69, 0}

\lstset
{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    stepnumber=2,
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    frame=single,
    rulecolor=\color{black},
    tabsize=3,
    captionpos=b,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    title=\lstname,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    morekeywords={},
    deletekeywords={}
}

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}

\lstdefinelanguage{json}{
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=lines,
    backgroundcolor=\color{background},
    literate=
    *{0}{{{\color{numb}0}}}{1}
    {1}{{{\color{numb}1}}}{1}
    {2}{{{\color{numb}2}}}{1}
    {3}{{{\color{numb}3}}}{1}
    {4}{{{\color{numb}4}}}{1}
    {5}{{{\color{numb}5}}}{1}
    {6}{{{\color{numb}6}}}{1}
    {7}{{{\color{numb}7}}}{1}
    {8}{{{\color{numb}8}}}{1}
    {9}{{{\color{numb}9}}}{1}
    {:}{{{\color{punct}{:}}}}{1}
    {,}{{{\color{punct}{,}}}}{1}
    {\{}{{{\color{delim}{\{}}}}{1}
    {\}}{{{\color{delim}{\}}}}}{1}
    {[}{{{\color{delim}{[}}}}{1}
    {]}{{{\color{delim}{]}}}}{1},
}

% Tables
\usepackage{booktabs} % horizontal lines in tables
\usepackage{tabularx} % additional table functions (new environent tabularx)
\usepackage{ltablex}
%\usepackage{ltxtable} % long tabularx tables
\usepackage{multirow} % connect multiple rows in tables
\usepackage{array} % additional table functions
\usepackage{ragged2e} % adds function to center, left, right text

% Caption
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf, justification=raggedright, format=hang]{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{position=below}
\captionsetup[figure]{position=below}

\begin{document}


\begin{lstlisting}[language=json,firstnumber=1,caption={Aufbau des JSON-Strings}]
{
"id": {
"board-id": 1,
"command-group-id": 2,
"command-id": 5 
},
"payload": {
}
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lccccl@{}}
        \toprule
        Command Name &
        \multicolumn{4}{c}{ID} &
        Payload \\
        \midrule
        SetSpeed &
        1 &
        1 &
        0 &
        1 &
        speed \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Auflistung aller Commands für die Kommunikation zwischen Raspberry Pi 1 und 2}
    \label{tab:Komponentenbeschreibung - Kommunikation - Commands}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the "normal" (or expected) output? I think a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would help us help you!

Comment: You can shorten your code by saying `\captionsetup{position=below}` (this will apply the option for all captions).

Comment: The problem is, that below the listing, the caption is centered. But under the table it is on the left side, which is the way I want it.

Comment: Use `\captionsetup{position=below,singlelinecheck=false}`. The `singlelinecheck` is true by default, making single lined captions centered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure single line captions are not centered, which is the default with `caption`, you can set `singlelinecheck=false` inside the `\captionsetup` command or the options when loading the `caption` package:

```
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}
```

or

```
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
```

Including the `singlelinecheck=false` in either of the options mentioned above, the output becomes

[image: Output]